# Magento secure URL directive?

Tags: magento-1.9, url, secure, template-directive

I'm using {{store url=""}} to build the URL for a CMS block. The block is later loaded within the HEAD tag to include a rel="stylesheet" link pointing to a CSS file.

My problem is that the store directive used in this context is giving the unsecure address (http instead of https).

How do I get the rel="stylesheet" link to point to the proper URL (in this case, the secure version)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can pass parameter : `_secure=1` And for force secure url `_force_secure=1`

See example :

```
<a href="{{store direct_url="" _secure=1}}">Link title</a>
```

And for Force Secure Url :

```
<a href="{{store direct_url="" _force_secure=1}}">Link title</a>
```

Hope this help.

Comment: @JulianM. Glad to hear that it helped. Happy Coding!

Answer (score 0):

You should also be able to use

```
<a href="{{config path='web/secure/base_url'}}">Link title</a>
```

Might have to add `web/secure/base_url` to allowed variables at `System > Permissions > Variables` first.